# arch-linux installation doubts

Tags: archlinux

I am new to arch-linux, following the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) to install it in a vbox on mac.

1. Following:

   `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

I am confused in one thing a bit, I booted from CD-Drive/USB. Wouldn't it mount to the /mnt in that USB's filesystem? Instead of the filesystem on the disk-drive.

2. When installing the base package group using

   `pacstrap /mnt base`

There is no root/pacstrap.in in my /root folder as suggested https://git.archlinux.org/arch-install-scripts.git/tree/pacstrap.in

Comment: Not a programming question; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe try our sister site [unix.se] but check their guidelines first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would mount the filesystem under the USB's filesystem, but that doesn't change the fact that /dev/sda1 belongs to another disk. You can think of this mount point (/mnt) as a pointer (if you've coded in C/C++) pointing to the actual hard drive. Whatever you write under /mnt is written to /dev/sda1

And the `pacstrap.in` is an install script which is installed inside the live environment. So it will just create a root directory structure and install the base system under that. By (loose) analogy, you wouldn't expect a MS Word (Libreoffice preferred) executable to be stored along with where you store your document, right?

Answer (score 0):

In Arch Linux or in any other Linux/Unix based file system, during the partitioning/Installation of the system usually the operating system needs some essential components like SWAP space , /boot, /home. If you are going to install it on the whole drive like mounting /root on /mnt then the essential parts of the file system are automatically created after mounting the root.
In the same scenario you can make separate partitions for each of the components and mount separately. Then as a whole you can install the base and base-devel packages